# Using resources and resource files for Android localization

Tags: android, localization, resources

Just trying to understand localizations and how it works.
I'm reading [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#using-framework) article about `string localizations` in `Android` applications. And everything is OK. I can create string `resources`, few folders (es, en, etc.) and it will works perfectly.

But if I understand correctly, it is a static way. I mean, I can create "by hand" this `resource` file, provide strings for any regions and then use it in my app. Am I right? Or there is a possibility, to create that resource file dynamically? Let say I have my strings with translations in the backend and I want to initialize it and then use?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for Localazy.

If you don't want to care about resources and XML files, just use [Localazy](https://localazy.com/android). It comes with a Gradle plugin that takes care of everything for you and it even integrates OTA updates automatically into your app - **updated translations and new languages are delivered online without resubmitting the app to stores**.

And you can manage all translations easily through a cloud-based interface with shared translations - translations are shared with all other apps on the platform so **you can get your app translated for free to up to 80 languages**.

The basic management for a typical app is free.